# SQL Server System Objects and Intellisense

Tags: sql-server, intellisense, master-system-database

I have created two stored procedures that I want to be available from all databases on SQL Server 2017. I created them in the master database, used sp_ as the prefix for both of them (e.g. `sp_MyProc1` and `sp_MyProc2`), and then ran `sp_ms_marksystemobject` on them to make them system objects.

I can indeed call them from any database and they work as expected.

The problem is that Intellisense doesn't know that they're there unless master is the default. It does recognize built in system procedures like `sp_HELP`. Is there another setting I need to change to make Intellisense recognize them? We're using SSMS v17.9. I tried putting them in the `sys` schema, but apparently SQL Server doesn't allow that on master.

Thank You,
Robbie

Comment: That's just a limitation of how intellisense works. You're stuck. I'm not even sure that Redgate SQL Prompt would do that. However, interesting test.

Comment: Thanks Grant. Do you know how the built in system stored procedures are recognized by Intellisense? Are they in the sys schema in Master? Or are they installed by default in every database? I'm still holding out for some magic bullet!

Comment: To my knowledge it's using the built-in language within the system itself. I forget the exact location, but it knows what SQL Server knows to be the correct language.